# скроллинг виджетов в bottom sheet(NestedScrollView)

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно, чтобы RecyclerView скроллился(с этим все в порядке), а TextView нет, т.е всегда оставался наверху bottom sheet.
Вот xml этого фрагмента:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#898989"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewR"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="dgd"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"


                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Ну просто вытащите `TextView` из `ScrollView`.

Comment: и куда его деть?

Comment: Например сделать корневым вертикальный `LinearLayout` в котором будет первым идти ваш `TextView`, а за ним `ScrollView`.

Comment: все равно не понимаю, у меня есть выдвижная панель(bottom sheet)
Nested Scroll View может содержать только один элемент. И деть TextView некуда больше

Answer (score 0):

Раз у вас используется `RecyclerView`, то дополнительный `NestedScrollView` тут вообще не нужен. Используйте следующую разметку:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#898989"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewR"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="dgd"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```